# The page has expired due to inactivity.

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

i copied my laravel project from server to my local machine and when i login server back my page where -> "The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again."

I tryied clear cache, clear session, and i look 2 pages of google and nothing hepled.
Do you have any ideas what i must to?

Comment: Check if the debug mode is enabled ? to see the origin error and i think it's because of the CSXF token !

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true and log file is clear(

Comment: Did you have `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your forms ?

Comment: its standart auth form

Comment: What is the session driver that you use in the `config/session.php`

Comment: 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

Comment: production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.
What i now see in error log

Comment: In this case execute this command `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: it done, but it didn`t help

Comment: And what about session `domain` in the `config/session.php` make it to null ! and what is the value of `SESSION_DRIVER` in the .env file ?

Comment: its null and SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: the next thing to check is the permission of the storage folder !!

Comment: Can you write to me in skype?
I

Comment: and how i can check permission?

Comment: what about gmail hangouts ?

Comment: I send to you an invitation in hangouts :)